# Google maps Activity view in existing Android application

Tags: android, eclipse, maps, implementation

I'm in the very beginning phase of android application programming in Eclipse. I have made an simple app with a main menu.

One of the options in the main menu should be an "google maps" view. How is it possible to do? Do I have to start from beginning with new project and new emulator, or are there a way to implement the map in this stage?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See [this `MapView` tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview).

I assume you have a single `Activity` class in your app now, you can just add another class to your project, to implement the `MapView` in.

Answer (score 0):

No you need not create new project. You can have any number of activities in the same application. Using intent you can cal those activities. Create a map activity. Follow the steps in the link given below to create the same.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHXa96-r8TY

All the best...